# Delta G and Temperature

Tags: molecular-biology

I'm now designing primers for PCR. I use Oligo analyzer to check the primer secondary structures.

**Ex:** Delta G:  -4.16 kcal/mole  Base Pairs: 4

```
5'        GCCGTCTAGCAGCACATAATG
            :  ||||  :         
3' GTAATACACGACGATCTGCCG
```

So my question is with delta G = -4.16, how do I know how much temperature degree can break these bonds?